# Did Thomas Jefferson write the Virginia Constitution in such a way that parts of the state can leave the state?

Tags: united-states

[Jerry Falwell, Jr](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jerry_Falwell_Jr.), president of [Liberty University](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liberty_University), appeared on [Fox and Friends](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fox_%26_Friends) on 13 March 2020, being interviewed about, among other things, "Vexit", a plan proposed by some West Virginians and Virginians to have part of western Virginia leave and become part of West Virginia

[Youtube link here](https://youtu.be/_4aR-6MrJjo?t=187) - go to 3:07 if the time link does not work, the first three minutes are not regarding Vexit.

In this interview he claims

> Thomas Jefferson wrote the Virginia Constitution so that counties, communities, cities, could leave Virginia, go to another state, without a war, because he didn't want the Revolutionary War to have to happen again, for people to escape tyranny.

Is there any truth to this claim?

Comment: My understanding is that there is some precedence for this, e.g. how West Virginia was created in the first place

Comment: @PCLuddite I understand that, but that was also an extraordinary time in the country.  The wiki article on West Virginia does not specify anything to the effect of what Falwell is claiming

Comment: Would Legal.SE be a better place for this?

Comment: It seems there are actually two claims here: that the Virginia Constitution allows secession, and that Jefferson wrote it. (Or perhaps Falwell is referring to a famous draft of the Virginia Constitution that Jefferson wrote, but that [citation-needed] wasn't used, rather than the enacted constitution.)

Comment: [Wikipedia says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constitution_of_Virginia#1776) "[Jefferson's] drafts of the Virginia constitution arrived too late to be incorporated into the final document," so at least half of this is wrong (not to mention the fact that Virginia has had multiple constitutions since then, so what was written in 1776 may not even apply today).

Comment: @jwodder: Wikipedia does say that, but the reference it gives leads nowhere, so I am not prepared to take their word on it yet.

Comment: @jwodder "The contributions of Jefferson to the Virginia Constitution can be unmistakably identified by comparing his texts with the Committee revision, with the amendments offered in Convention, and with the final Constitution; certain parts are indisputably Jefferson’s in phraseology and substance. Of all the plans that are known, only Jefferson’s can be regarded as a complete, finished, detailed form of government: all others that are known were outlines, some merely describing and distributing the major powers..." https://founders.archives.gov/documents/Jefferson/01-01-02-0161-0001

Comment: I'm ok with migrating it to law or politics if it seems off topic here.

Comment: Is the question whether the US Constitution provides for secession? That's a legal question. Or is the question about Jefferson's intent in writing the Virginia Constitution? That's a historical question. (Then there's the problem that he didn't write "the" Virginia Constitution)

Comment: @user6726: I think the key question is whether the *Virginia* Constitution allows for it, whatever the intent. Whether Jefferson wrote it or not is a side question that you might choose to address or not. (But I am not a Law.SE regular, so I am may not fully understand how things are done here.)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a question of law, it's a question of history.

Comment: @PCLuddite precedent.

Comment: @user6726 Virginia's constitution is a law.  The question is therefore on topic.

Comment: @phoog, the question does not ask if Virginia's constitution allows it. Are you proposing a re-write of the question so that that is what it asks?

Comment: @phoog thanks for the correction. I commented on this when it was on skeptics.se and am not very familiar with legal terminology

Comment: The consent of the legislature of Virginia to the separation of Kentucky was passed three times.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer:

I don't know.  Some of the clauses in the US constitution make me think that unilateral secession from a state was not allowed in any state constitution in 1787.

Long Answer:

Another factor to consider in relation to the transfer of counties from Virginia to West Virginia is Article Four, Section 3 of the United States Constitution adopted in 1788.

> Section. 3.
>   New States may be admitted by the Congress into this Union; but no new State shall be formed or erected within the Jurisdiction of any other State; nor any State be formed by the Junction of two or more States, or Parts of States, without the Consent of the Legislatures of the States concerned as well as of the Congress.
>
> The Congress shall have Power to dispose of and make all needful Rules and Regulations respecting the Territory or other Property belonging to the United States; and nothing in this Constitution shall be so construed as to Prejudice any Claims of the United States, or of any particular State.

https://www.archives.gov/founding-docs/constitution-transcript[1](https://www.archives.gov/founding-docs/constitution-transcript)

So the Federal Constitution of 1788 would seem to override the Virginia constitution of 1776.

Note that Article Four, Section 2 says:

> Section. 2.
>   The Citizens of each State shall be entitled to all Privileges and Immunities of Citizens in the several States.

So if citizens of Virginia had the right to unilateral secesssion from Virginia, the citizens of every other state would have the right to unilateral secession from that state.

And Article VI says:

> This Constitution, and the Laws of the United States which shall be made in Pursuance thereof; and all Treaties made, or which shall be made, under the Authority of the United States, shall be the supreme Law of the Land; and the Judges in every State shall be bound thereby, any Thing in the Constitution or Laws of any State to the Contrary notwithstanding.

https://www.archives.gov/founding-docs/constitution-transcript[1](https://www.archives.gov/founding-docs/constitution-transcript)

This indicates that if the Virginia constitution made unilateral secession from Virginia legal, Article Four, Section 3 would override it and make unilateral secession from Virginia unconstitutional.

So if unilateral secession from Virginia (or any other state) was constitutional according to that state's constitution in 1787-1789, Article Four, Section 2 would make it constitutional in every other state, while Article Six and Article Four, Section 3 would forbid unilateral secession from any state.

So I deduce that if the constitution of any state in 1787-89 made unilateral secession from that state legal, the United States Constitution that was written and adopted in 1787-1789 would have contained contradictory clauses.   I find it a little hard to believe that a bunch of politicians familiar with the constitutions of their respective states would have overlooked any contradictions in those articles in the US constitution they were writing.

Comment: No, [Article IV, Section 2 (the "Privileges and Immunities Clause")](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Privileges_and_Immunities_Clause) does not mean that the Virginia Constitution can give citizens of other states the right to secede from their states; it means that states can't discriminate against citizens of other states.

Comment: The Virginian constitution predates the US constitution by a decade, so it could well be that the claim is correct - that is how the Virginian constitution was written, but later context changes made it moot.

Comment: Put another way. Even if it said that when adopted, it is of purely historical interest today since the U.S. Constitution forbids Virginia from doing so and has imposed this limitation since 1789.

Answer (score -2):

Re. The only state in the union that can secede is Texas, who joined 1845 and it was written into the Texas State Constitution. That's the way it was, dont know if it changed. Least it was that way when I grew up in Texas and studied Texas history.

Re Virginia. The problem in Va is that the southern half all the way to Norfolk is conservative. The Northern,Va area which has the counties of Arlington, Alexandria in Fairfax county, Fairfax county in its entirety, Prince William,Falcquier are densely populated with liberals. West Va is more conservative. Consequently, the southern  area to the east coast, Chesapeake bay areas are always out voted by the liberals. It could be a powerful move for the Commonwealth  of Va to split the state,but would finally give those people a vote in elections if they ceded to WVa. Doubt if Richmond State Capitol, Congressmen, state legumes would ever let this happen. Lived there forty yrs.

Comment: Arguably, Texas can [divide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Texas_divisionism) into as many as five states - that law has never been repealed.

Comment: Except all of this is moot, because the US Constitution overrides it all as explained in M. A. Golding's answer.